# How many draws?

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a game, with $n$ players, $n$ even. Each match involves exactly 2 players. I want to compute the total number of combinations you can have at first round. For example, for $n=2$, just 1 combination. For $n=4$, you can have $3$:

1) player1 vs player2, player3 vs player4

2) p1 vs p3, p2 vs p4

3) p1 vs p4, p2 vs p3

For $n=6$ you can have 15 combinations:

1) (1,2), (3,4), (5,6)

2) (1,2), (3,5), (4,6)

3) (1,2), (3,6), (4,5)

4) (1,3), (2,4), (5,6)

5) (1,3), (2,5), (4,6)

6) (1,3), (2,6), (4,5)

7) (1,3), (2,3), (5,6)

8) (1,4), (2,5), (3,6)

9) (1,4), (2,6), (3,5)

10)(1,5), (2,3), (4,6)

11)(1,5), (2,4), (3,6)

12)(1,5), (2,6), (3,4)

13)(1,6), (2,3), (4,5)

14)(1,6), (2,4), (3,5)

15)(1,6), (2,5), (3,4)

Calling $d(n)$ the number of different draws with $n$ players, I have $d(2)=1$, $d(4)=3$, $d(6)=15$. What is $d(n)$ for $n$ arbitrary even?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you require the number of pairings possible in the first round given $2n$ players sign up for a tournament. Let us use a recursive method to calculate the same.

Let the number of pairings of the $2n$ players be given by $P_n$. You have correctly identified that when $n =1, P_n =1$. Now, as we have $n$ pairs, we choose any one player. This player’s partner can be chosen in $(2n-1)$ ways. But, there still remains for us to decide about the remaining $(n-1)$ pairs.

Thus, $$P_1 = 1, P_n = (2n-1)P_{n-1} \implies P_n = (2n-1)\times (2n-3)\ldots 3\times 1 $$ $$\boxed{ P_n = \frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}}$$

Comment: Your $n$ is such that the number of players is $2n$, while in the question the number of players was $n$ with the condition $n$ even.

Answer (score 1):

It is the product of all the odd positive numbers less than $n$, [A001147](https://oeis.org/A001147).

$$d(n)=(n-1)(n-3)(n-5)\dots 5\cdot 3\cdot 1$$

This is because when you pick an opponent for Player 1, you have $n-1$ different people choose from. After that, you need to pick an opponent for the next player who is not already drawn, and you have $n-3$ choices this time. And so on.